# IIS7 -- how to configure server to serve cxml

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I am trying to deploy a silverlight pivot site, and I ran into the following problem: cxml is only being served correctly from a single directory in the server. If a request the cxml file from it, I get the xml response. If I try another directory, I get a 500 error.

I already added the mime type to the server.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add that to the list of mime types, its probable that the specific directory where it works it is included locally.
You can add it globally using AppCmd.exe:

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/staticContent /+"[fileExtension='.cxml',mimeType='text/xml']"
```

Or use Mime Types feature in IIS Manager.

For more info: 
http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it seems that that was the problem. There was also some kind of a conflict between the local and server config with cxml. Once I solved those, it began to work.